# i have this code. It is supposed to classify the segment files with the ratings in sys.argv[5].But it keeps having error

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have the following code tha uses FFmpeg . It has 5 argv and it takes in filename,video,segment size, start time, end time, ratings. thats supposed to let me classify segments many times with my ratings "PG G M18..."  but there's this error,

```
"File "C:\c.py",line 92, in <module> os.rename<filename + str(x), filename + str(x) + classification)
WindowsError: [Error2] The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Ive tried to edit many times but this error still persists. Anyone have any idea what could this error mean and anyway to solve it?

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os

#change hh:mm:ss to seconds:
def getSeconds(sec):
    l = sec.split(':')
    return int(l[0])* 3600 + int(l[1])* 60 + float(l[2])

def get_total_time(filename):

    proc = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-i", filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    lines = proc.communicate()[1]
    target = [line for line in lines.split('\n') if 'Duration:' in line][0]
    time = target.split('Duration: ')[-1].split(',', 1)[0]
    return time


#check command line arguments
if len(sys.argv) < 5:
    print "Error: not enough arguments"
    sys.exit()

#save filename to file_name
file_name = sys.argv[1]
if not file_name.endswith('mpg'):
    print 'Error! File extension not supported'
    sys.exit()
# save a size of chunk in chunk
segsize = int(sys.argv[2])
chunk = (segsize * 1024)

# get time of starting censorship in seconds
start_censorship = getSeconds(sys.argv[3])

# get time of ending censorship in seconds
end_censorship   = getSeconds(sys.argv[4])

classification = sys.argv[5]
if classification not in ['P','PG','G','NC16','M18','R21']:
    print "Error: invalid classification"
    sys.exit()

#initialize variable for extension 
file_ext = ''


# if extension exists then save it into file_ext
if '.' in file_name:
    # split file_name on two parts from right
    file_ext = sys.argv[1].split('.')[-1]


# file_name without extension    
filename = '.'.join(file_name.split('.')[:-1])

# total_time of file in seconds
total_time = getSeconds(get_total_time(file_name))

print total_time



#open file    
in_file = open(file_name,'rb')


#read first chunks
s = in_file.read(chunk)

in_file.seek(0, 2)
file_size = in_file.tell()
chunks = (file_size / chunk) + 1

chunk_time = total_time/ file_size * chunk

#close input file    
in_file.close()

#loop for each chunk
for x in range(0, chunks):
    # starting time of current chunk
    t1 = chunk_time*x
    # ending time of current chunk    
    t2 = chunk_time*(x+1)

    if t2 < start_censorship or t1 > end_censorship:
        pass
    else:
        if os.path.exists(filename + str(x) + 'x'):
            os.rename(filename + str(x) + 'x', filename + str(x))
        os.rename(filename + str(x), filename + str(x) + classification)

    #read next bytes
```

Comment: The error means that the existing filename you are searching for does not exist in your root directory. I would add a debugging line above line 92 such as: `print filename + str(x)`  and ensure that a file by that name exists in your root directory

Answer (score 0):

In that last `for` loop it looks like you are possibly renaming multiple files -- where do the original files come from?

Or, asked another way, for every chunk that is not censored you are renaming a file -- is that really what you want?

Comment: I think this is more a comment  than an answer

Comment: What do you mean come from?

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking whether `filename + str(x)` exists before you try to rename it. Either check first, or put it in a `try` block and catch `OSError` (which `WindowsError` subclasses). Either that or you're missing an indent on the second rename.

Comment: i have tried changing the below part to     if t2 < start_censorship or t1 > end_censorship:
        out_file = open(filename + str(x), 'wb')
    else:
        out_file = open(filename + str(x) + classification , 'wb')
    #write bytes
    out_file.write(in_file.read(chunk))
    #close output file
    out_file.close()
    #read next bytes
but it everytime i run it will just duplicate if i add 2 or more ratings

Comment: Code in comments loses all its formatting so I can't read that. You have the basic idea - you can only rename a file that exists. You need to debug it from there based on what you actually want the code to do.

Comment: just need it to rename the files without duplicating it if i run multiple times. This error has been plaguing me so long!